# commandButton actionListener is not working in PrimeFaces page with viewParam

Tags: jsf, primefaces, actionlistener, viewparams

I found a weird behavior in JSF/PrimeFaces and ask your help to understand and get around it. The actionListener method in a commandButton is executed just once.

Contextualization:

I put a link in start page of my project to a second page, renderized as follows:

```
http://localhost:8080/MeusTestes-war/faces/somepage.xhtml?id=1
```

Notice there is a parameter sent by query string.

The somepage.xhtml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>

    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{someBean.id}" required="true" />
        <f:viewAction action="#{someBean.init}" />
    </f:metadata>

    <h:body>
        <h:form id="form1">
            <p:commandButton id="teste1" 
                             value="Teste" 
                             actionListener="#{someBean.doTeste}" />
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

As you can see, its extremely simple. Notice there is a metadata section doing the parameter reception and the execution of init() method. In page body there is a p:commandButton and a actionListener pointing to doTeste().

There is my Bean:

```
@Named(value = "someBean")
@ViewScoped
public class SomeBean implements Serializable {

    private int id;

    public SomeBean() {
    }

    public int getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(int id) { this.id = id; }

    public void init() {
        System.out.println("init " + id);
    }

    public void doTeste(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        System.out.println("doTeste " + id);
    }

}
```

Well, now the mysterious behavior:

1) When page is loaded, as expected, the init() method shows a message with the correct property value got by viewParam.
2) Firing the button, as expected too, the doTeste() method shows a message with the correct property value.
However,
3) Firing the button again, nothing happens!

Other facts:

If I remove the metadata section the doTeste() method is executed as many times as the button is clicked, which is supposed to happen. But the property, obviously, is not initialized.

If I switch the button definition from p:commandButton to h:commandButton, the doTeste() method is executed as expected AND the property is initialized. But I lose the PrimeFaces pattern.

My question:

How to do the commandButton actionListener from PrimeFaces behave the way is expected? (executing the method each time it is fired)

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [f:viewParam with Converter and ViewScoped exception out when invoke the second ajax request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526431/fviewparam-with-converter-and-viewscoped-exception-out-when-invoke-the-second-a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you for testing purposes add a `<p:growl id="msgs"/>` and add `update="msgs"` to the button you'll see that validation fails on subsequent requests (because of `required="true"` on the `viewParam`).

So you can either

1. remove `required="true"`. Probably a bad idea since you need it.
2. add the parameter to the commandButton with `<f:param name="id" value="#{someBean.id}"/>`
3. use OmniFaces `<o:viewParam>`.

There is a more technical explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526431/fviewparam-with-converter-and-viewscoped-exception-out-when-invoke-the-second-a).

Comment: The message shows a validation error, value required. But I didn't change the page, the view scope must not be lost, right?

Comment: This behavior just happens on PrimeFaces. Is that a bug?

Comment: No it should be the same bean, you can be totally sure by printing to log in the constructor, but if you're using javax.faces.view.ViewScoped it's the same. As BalusC says "the <f:viewParam> runs on every single HTTP request, also on postbacks", that's the problem. Yes I'd say it's a bug that will be fixed some day, for now you can just add the parameter to the p:commandButton. h:commandButton don't use ajax maybe that's the reason it works

Comment: I found a lot of posts mentioning some like that, the most involving ajax in components. I think it's a serious issue. Not all can be easily overcome.

Comment: @RobinsonRK IMO it's not an issue, and looks like you're not trying to understand how to solve the problem. BalusC is very explicit in the duplicate Q/A: pass the paramater set in `<f:viewParam>` as a parameter in your `UICommand`s (e.g. `<p:commandButton>`) or use `<o:viewParam>` from OmniFaces which is suited for your desired behavior. It's up to you to take one of these solutions or to keep ranting about how JSF works.

Comment: You don't need to throw stones @luiggi-mendoza, I would not ask if I don't needed your help. It still looks like a concept bug for me.

Comment: Please @jaqen-hghar, post the answer.